# Deploy compiled file to AWS Greengrass V2

Tags: c++, c, amazon-s3, aws-iot-greengrass

I have a compiled file of C/C++, and I want to deploy this file to core device in Greengrass V2. If I use GUI, what do I need to change in recipe.YAML file to deploy successfully?

For Example: After compiled C/C++ file I have helloworld.out file, how can I deploy helloworld.out file and make it run in core device of Greengrass V2.
With Python, I just deploy normally but with C/C++ I don't know how to do it?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

With Greengrass v2, you need to put in the recipe yaml file the command to execute your C++ application. For python you might have done this:

```
Lifecycle:
  Run: |
    python3 -u {artifacts:path}/hello_world.py
```

Well in C++, something like this should work:

```
Lifecycle:
  Run: |
    ./{artifacts:path}/helloworld.out
```

Comment: Thank you. But I changed recipe file as your tutorial but the output is always not found.

Comment: You can change this: `./{artifacts:path}/helloworld.out` 
by the absolute path on your drive.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved this problem. But it is not `./{artifacts:path}/helloworld.out`, it must be `/{artifacts:path}/./helloworld.out` and must change Execute from None to All in Permission part.

Answer (score 0):

After read document carefully and have some advice I could solve my problem.

I changed Lifecycle part in recipe file:

```
Lifecycle:
   Run: | 
      /{artifacts:path}/./helloworld.out
```

And Don't forget to change **Execute** Part from None to All(or Owner).
If not you will get error about Permission.